# Rails dropdown menu to select object for text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield, form-helpers, collection-select

I am building a rails form and have an interesting problem I am trying to solve. I can't seem to find anything online to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

**Is it possible to use a dropdown menu to select the :object_name for a text field?** 
In my head, I am picturing a collection_select form helper nested within a text_field form helper, though not sure this is possible.

In the form, I'd like the user to select the proper :object_name from an array

```
[:object_1, :object_2, :object_3, :object_4]
```

then give that entry a value with the text field

```
text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
```

The objects are all db columns in the same model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using `jquery`.

On change of the object names dropdown value, change the `name` attribute of the text field.

```
$('#selectObjectName').change(function(){
  var field = document.getElementById("id-of-the-text-field-to-be-changed");
  field.setAttribute("name", "value-came-from-the-selected-dropdown"); 
})
```